# Hibernate autogenerated SQL table is not being created

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, hibernate, maven

Hi and thank you all for reading my issue,

I'm working with hibernate in a maven project in eclipse, my dbms is mysql with xampp. One of my classes that must be a table inside the database is not being created in the database, do not know why.

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'db_p1_mdai.tuiteos' doesn't exist
```

Here is my code for the no-autogenerated class/table.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Tuiteos")
public class TuiteoVO implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
@GenericGenerator(name="increment", strategy="increment")
private int id_tuiteo;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="id_usuario_fk")
private UsuarioVO usuario_fk;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="id_tuit_fk")
private TuitVO tuit_fk;

private boolean tuit_propio;

private boolean like;

private boolean retuit;
```

The rest of the class consist in a dumb class, constructors, default and parameterized, getters, setters, equals and toString, so I will skip it.

Here are the referenced classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Usuarios")
public class UsuarioVO implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
@GenericGenerator(name="increment", strategy="increment")
private int id_usuario;

private String nombre;

private String arroba;

private String correo;

private String password;

private String fechaRegistro;

private String descripcion;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "id_usuario_emisor")
private Set<MensajeVO> mensajes;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "usuario_fk")
private Set<TuiteoVO> tuiteos;
```

The OneToMany relationship with Mensaje class works perfectly, so I wont paste the code.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Tuits")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class TuitVO implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
@GenericGenerator(name="increment", strategy="increment")
protected int id_tuit;

protected String texto;

protected String fecha;

protected String hora;

protected int likes;

protected int retuits;

@ManyToMany(targetEntity = HashtagVO.class, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
@JoinTable(name = "Tuit_Hashtag", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_tuitt"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_hashtagg"))
protected Collection<HashtagVO> lista_hashtags;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "tuit_fk")
protected Set<TuiteoVO> tuiteos;
```

By last, persistence.xml:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="es.unex.cum.mdai.*">
        <class>es.unex.cum.mdai.vo.UsuarioVO</class>
        <class>es.unex.cum.mdai.vo.TuitVO</class>
        <class>es.unex.cum.mdai.vo.HashtagVO</class>
        <class>es.unex.cum.mdai.vo.MensajeVO</class>
        <class>es.unex.cum.mdai.vo.TuiteoVO</class>
        <class>es.unex.cum.mdai.vo.TuitRespuestaVO</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver"
                value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DB_P1_MDAI?serverTimezone=UTC" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, I got the answer. After a long research along the weekend, headaches, wishes of death and no solution found out for the problem, finally I talked with my teacher and he saw the problem at the moment, and, besides I'm an idiot, the problem was.. (drum roll):

```
private boolean like;
```

I was doing a kind of sql injection to myself, due to "like" is a reserved word for SQL "Tuiteos" table was not being created. I will never forget this experience.